# Mallet, how to use ExpGain and GradientGain method to construct a FeatureSelector

Tags: nlp, mallet

I want to test the accuracy of a text classifier built with **Mallet**,there are 4 feature selection methods available.(*FeatureCounts,InfoGain,ExpGain and GradientGain*).
i want to know how to use **ExpGain** and **GradientGain**.

Eg:
FeatureSelector fselector=new FeatureSelector
                        (new FeatureCounts.Factory(),numOfFeature);

Answer (score 1):

Each of the classes you mentioned is a subclass of RankedFeatureVector. They apply different rules to generate a score for each feature. You can then construct a new FeatureSelection object by passing the RankedFeatureVector and the number of features you want to keep.

[This API page](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/api/cc/mallet/types/class-use/FeatureSelection.html) shows how to use FeatureSelection objects to train classifiers.